# Identical forms interfering

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem with two forms, that is being submitted by the same button.
When the first form is submitted it's being hidden and the other form is showed.
Now when i click the button on the second form, the variable value still contains 'give' from the selectbox in the first form.

What am i doing wrong?

**Jquery code:**

```
$('.submit_button').click(function() {
    var value = $(".input_action").val();
    alert(value);

    switch(value) {
        case 'give':
            $('#content_wrapper').hide();
            $('#send_wrapper').show();
            break;

        default:
            alert("default");
            break;
    }
});
```

---

**Html code:**
***Form 1:***

```
<div id='content_wrapper'>
<form class='form_content' method='post' action=''>
<select name='action' class='input_action'>
<option selected='give'>Give</option>
</select>
<input class='submit_button' type='button' name='button' value='submit'>                  
</form>
```

---

***Form 2:***

```
<div id='send_wrapper'>
<form name='form_content' class='form_content' method='post' action=''>
<input name='input_action' class='input_action' value='' type='hidden'>
<input class='submit_button' type='button' name='button' value='submit'>
</form>
</div>
```

---

Comment: The [*selected*](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/forms.html#selected) attribute is boolean, it does not need a value. Sometimes `selected="selected"` is used but it is not required and has no effect on the value. `selected='give'` is pointless and does nothing that `selected` by itself wont achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(".input_action").val()` will always give you the value of the *first* element that matches *in the document*.

If you want to get the one from the current form, then you need to find the current form and then find the matching element within that.

The context of the event handler will be the element clicked, so you can get that with `this`.

You can get the form using the `form` property.

You can then use the jQuery `find` method to get the element you want.

```
var value = $( this.form ).find('.input_action').val();
```

Comment: I figured it was something like this :-) Thank you very much Quentin, it works perfectly now.

Comment: Given that the name of the control is "input_action" then the value can be accessed using `this.form.input_action.value`. Oh sorry, no jQuery and less to type. :-(

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is - you're not finding a proper `.input_action` element.
Try this:

```
$('.submit_button').click(function() {
    var form = $(this).parent("form");
    var value = form.find(".input_action").val();
    alert(value);

    switch(value) {
        case 'give':
            $('#content_wrapper').hide();
            $('#send_wrapper').show();
            break;

        default:
            alert("default");
            break;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First close your first div

```
<div id='content_wrapper'>
<form class='form_content' method='post' action=''>
<select name='action' class='input_action'>
<option selected='give'>Give</option>
</select>
<input class='submit_button' type='button' name='button' value='submit'>                  
</form>
</div>
```

your second form is Ok

and in your jquery script change 'give' case to 'Give'

here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r54GM/)

Comment: The div was a typo on stackoverflow :)